# Did Goddess Lakshmi or Goddess Saraswati (not Adishakthi or Durga) kill any demons?

Tags: lakshmi, durga, saraswati

I know Parvati Devi killed Demon Mahishasura with help of other Shaktis by manifesting into Goddess Durga. So, Adishakti killed Mahishasura through Parvathi Devi. I think same is the case with Goddess Kaali. But on the contrary, did Lakshmi Devi or Saraswati Devi kill any demons without manifesting into Adi Shakti or Goddess Durga?

Comment: There's the famous story of Lakshmi killing the demon Kohlasura in the city of Karaveerapura, which is why Karaveerapura is now known as Kohlapur.  Kohlapur is the place that Lakshmi goes to in the story of Venkateshwara, either when she leaves Vishnu after he massages Bhrigu's foot, or when Venkateshwara turns to stone and Padmavathi and Lakshmi go off to two different locations.  (It's not clear to me which; it's possible that Lakshmi initially lives in Kohlapur, then comes to Tirupati when Venakteshwara marries Padmavathi, and then when he turns to stone she goes back to Kohlapur.)

Comment: Anagha Lakshmi (wife of Dattatrya) had killed jambasura who has occupied heaven.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan As far as my knowledge is concerned, she went to Kohlapur to do penance after strife with Vishnu. she then came to Vishnu after His marriage with Padmavathi. Did she again go back to Kohlapur after Venkateswara becoming stone? Didn't she become small idol on the left side of Venkateswara chest? Ok, where is this story of demon Kohlasura mentioned ?

Comment: Maha laksmi and Maha saraswati killed demons. But they are slightly different from  Lakshmi who is the wife of Vishnu and Saraswati who is Brahma's wife. Mahalakshmi killed mahishasura and mahasaraswati killed shumbha+nishumbha. Goddesses varahi, vaishnavi, brahmi who are saktis to vishnu and brahma respectively helped adi sakti in killing of demons

Comment: @moonstar2001 Where did you get the idea that Mahalakshmi killed Mahaishasura and Mahasaraswati killed Shumbha and Nishumbha?  The Saptashati says that Durga killed Mahishasura, and Ambika killed Shumbha and Nishumbha.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan read devi mahatmyam properly.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I have read it.  It says that Durga came from the combined energies of Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva and fought Mahishasura, and it says Ambika/Kaushiki came from the body of Parvati and fought with Shumbha and Nishumbha.  What am I missing?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan When divided into 3 parts, second part of the text is considered mahalaxmi vaibhavam & the final part that of mahasaraswati. For easy reference: http://www.bhagavadgitausa.com/DEVI_MAHATMYAM.htm   "
It is also known as Candi or Durga Saptasati (seven hundred Mantras). Golden yellow Durga presents Herself as MahaKali, MahaLakshmi and MahaSarasvati; thus, chapter one is for Kali, two to four for Lakshmi and five to thirteen for Sarasvati.  "

Comment: Goddess parvati killed mahishasura.lakshmi and saraswati are mild form of goddess parvati

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Mahishasura according to Devi-Mahatmya(Chapter 2 to 5) was killed by Mahalaksmi**.**The Rishi of this Madhyama-Charitra of Devi-Mahatmya (Sri Sri Chandi) is Sri Vishnu Himself**, and Devata is Mahalaksmi. She appeared from the collected aura (Tejas) of Brahma-Vishnu-Shiva and the devas, who were very very angry because of the oppression by Mahishasura.(chapter 2, mantras 9-13).**But She of course is one form of Adi Shakti. Also, Kamala,a form of Lakshmi, is one of the Ten Mahavidyas and Her Bhairava is Sri Vishnu.So Devi Lakshmi is also Para Shakti Herself!**

There are various forms of Mahalakshmi mentioned in Sri Sri Chandi. One of such forms is worshipped as the Kolhapur (also known as Karavir) Mahalakshmi temple, which is considered  one of the 51 Shakti-peethas.(An original image is enclosed which shows Her form as Mahalakshmi with his vahana Lion clearly visible as per the Dhyana-Mantra mentioned in Sri Sri Chandi)The description of Mahalakshmi according to the Pradhaanika-Rahasya of Sri Sri Devimahatmya is

> **srvasyadyaa mahalakshmi strigunaa parameswari/..matulingam gadaam khetam paanapaatram cha vibrati/ nagam lingam cha yonim cha bibhtati nripa murdhani// meaning She holds matulinga(a fruit), gada, khetaka,panapatra and on Her head there are naga, linga and yoni. This form is seen at Kolhapur.**

.[image]

Parvati in Her own form did NOT kill any demon.

[image]

I have added an image of the starting of the second character (Mahishasurasainyavadhah) from Sri Sri Chandi by Udbodhan page 81 that mentions "Om asya srimadhyamacharitrasya vishnur rishih malakshmi devata usnik chhandah saakamvari shaktih durga bijam vayus tattvam yajurvedah svarupam MAHALAKSHMI-PRITI-ARTHAM madhyamacharitra-jape viniyogah" and then describes one dhyana-mantra of Mahalakshmi.

Further page 82 gives the original and meaning of slokas from LAKSHMI-TANTRA that mentions that

> Devi Lakshmi told Indra: I am Mahalakshmi myself.In sayambhuva manvantara, I again appeared for killing Mahisasura and benefiting all devas.

**Addition**

Goddess Mahasarasvati killed Shumbha and Nishumbha according to Sri Sri Chandi.

Durga Devi is said to killed the demon Durgama.

Comment: Even Devi Bhagwat mentions the Goddess introducing herself as Mahalakshmi while fighting Mahishasura.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, goddess Lakṣmī killed a demon named Kolāsura.**

The reference to Mahālakṣmī killing Kolāsura is found in the Skanda Purāṇa Verse 4.1.5.78, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50879/17833).

> त्रैलोक्यं कोलरूपेण त्रासयंतं महासुरम् ।
>  विनिहत्य स्थितां तत्र
> रम्ये कोलापुरे पुरे ॥ ७८ ॥
>
> > 78. A great Asura (Kolāsura) was frightening the three worlds in the form of a boar. The goddess (Lakṣmī) killed that demon and stayed in the beautiful city
> >     of Kolhāpur ever since.
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare