# Why is only Durga associated with Devi?

Tags: lakshmi, durga, saraswati

As we have already established in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10138/who-is-adi-shakti-and-durga), Devi(AdiShakti) incarnates as Durga, Lakshmi and Saraswati. Shaivas associate Durga with Devi as she is Shiva (their ishta devata)'s consort. However, even Shaktas, who worship Devi as the TriDevi, give Durga more importance than the rest. Why is this so? Even their names are from Durga (Shakti).

Now, in the answer, please explain why is **only** Durga associated with Devi? Is there anything to do with scriptures? If there is any evidence (e.g. scriptures,folklore,etc) of the rest of the TriDevi being associated with Devi, please put it in the answer.Also,please tell me about the different goddesses associated with Devi as per the sects(e.g.Ganaptyas,etc).

Also,to avoid confusion,**only** use the names Durga (for the wife of Shiva),Lakshmi(for the wife of Vishnu), Saraswati (for the wife of Brahma) and Devi (for the supreme goddess/AdiShakti).

Please clear my doubts.

Comment: The link you have posted is not a valid source in the first place.It is the concerned user's subjective opinion.

Comment: Adi Para Shakti is Lalita MahaTripura Sundari(also known as Rajarajeswari),the presiding Deity of the Sri Chakra.All the other Goddesses are her incarnations or Rupas(forms).

Comment: He has given wrong meaning of names of Goddesses, Saraswati = Sara(essence)+Swati(sound), that is essence of sound which is Om. Lakshmi = One who has given Aksha or eyes to view creation, while Parvati is Shakti herself. Shakti means energy that is required to sustain the universe. We are made up of universal energy, while sound and light are part of it, hence energy/Adi Shakti is Supreme.

Comment: In Shiva Purana, it is mentioned that Shakti(cosmic mother) represents bindu(manifestation) while Shiva(cosmic father) represents Nada(subtle infinite sound) and creation happens from their union Ardhnarishwar. In the beginning there was nothing, only Shiva(that means empty universe filled with consciousness). Shakti(matter) was born out of him and their union resulting in entire universe. Of course, Vaishnavas have something else to say

Comment: @Rickross Please explain why is **only** Durga associated with Devi?

Comment: Also guys please use the abovegiven names as when you say Shakti,i am not really sure who she refers to.Thank you

Comment: @KVickneshvara It is not so, as answered in your other question: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/are-there-sects-for-lakshmi-or-saraswati

Comment: The comments here and the descriptions given are very good. I believe all devathas are same. Recently I started chanting Sri Mahalakshmi nama and stotras. After few days I had some dream/darshan of Chamundi devi. I was surprised. Then I reaslied that all (Sri Lakshmi, Sri Gauri, Sri Kali) are same and we are fooled because of diff names and forms. Energy is same. I think if you pray to one, u r praying to all forms and names..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily answered by using only the [Durga Sapta Sloki](http://www.aghori.it/durga_sapta_sloki_eng.htm) as the reference,which is a part of the famous [Devi Mahatyam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi_Mahatmya) found in the Markandeya Purana.

> The Durga Sapta Sloki (Seven verses to Durga) was taught by the
>   Goddess herself to Lord Shiva, to realize our objectives in the Kali
>   age. This is also called Amba Sthuthi. These seven verses are a
>   selection from the Devi Mahatmya. **It is believed that reading these
>   verses is equivalent to read the full text of Devi Mahatmya.**
>
> atha durgāsaptaślokī
>
> śiva uvāca |
>
> devī tvaṃ bhaktasulabhe sarvakāryavidhāyinī |
>
> kalau hi kāryasiddhayarthamupāyaṃ brūhi yatrataḥ ||
>
> Shiva said:
>
> Oh Goddess who can be easily approached by devotion, who helps us to
>   get all actions done. Please tell me the trick of achieving result for
>   these actions in Kali age.
>
> devyuvāca |
>
> śṛṇu deva pravakṣyami kalau sarvaiṣṭasādhanam
>
> mayā tavaiva snehenāpyambāstutiḥ prakāśyate ||
>
> Goddess said:
>
> Oh god, please hear what I say, which is the one fulfilling all
>   desires in Kali age. Due to my love for you, I am telling you this
>   prayer to Mother Goddess.
>
> om asya śrīdurgāsaptaślokīstotramahāmantrasya
>
> nārāyaṇa ṛṣiḥ । anuṣṭupādīni chandāṃsi ।
>
> **śrīmahākālīmahālakṣmīmahāsarasvatyo devatāḥ ।**
>
> **śrī jagadambāprītyartha pāṭhe viniyogaḥ** ॥
>
> Of this Durga Sapta Sloki, Narayana is the Rishi, Anushtup (eight
>   syllables in a pada) and others is the meter, **Goddess Mahakali,
>   Goddess Mahalakshmi and Goddess Mahasarasvati are the deities and it
>   is recited for the love of Shri Jagadamba (Mother of the Universe).**

So,when you see that the Devata of this Durga mantra are three Goddesses Mahakali,Mahalakshmi and Mahasraswati, it easy to conclude that Jagadamba Durga(to please whom this mantra is chanted)  **is a combined form of all the three aforesaid Goddesses and thus is superior to each of them considered individually.**

So,that's basically the reason why Durga Devi is given more importance than other forms of Devis or in your words "only associated with Devi."

And,btw Devi Durga is not only a combined from of various Devis but she is a combined form of various Devas also.