# What is the purpose of Maa Baglamukhi Yantra?

Tags: rituals, tradition, yantra, bagalamukhi

Recently heard about 'Maa Baglamukhi Yantra' so was curious to know more about this yantra.

[image]

My questions:

1. What exactly is the purpose of this yantra?
2. Who was the first person who used or we can say was originator of this yantra?
3. Any other interesting facts (worth sharing) associated with this yantra?

Comment: The purpose is to worship the Goddess in the Yantra.. Do u know what  the purpose of a Yantra in general is? I will try to answer upon seeing ur reply.

Comment: Not really to be honest @Rickross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is the purpose of this yantra?

First, we need to know what the purpose of a Yantra in general is.

In Hinduism, although the God is essentially stated to be Nirguna, but Saguna worship is mainly recommended, as worshipping the form-less is basically an impossible task.

And, for that purpose, symbols (*Pratik*) are introduced in various scriptures, in which we invoke the presence first and then worship the deities.

In Vedas, fire is the mode, in Upanishads Om is the Pratik, in Puranas it is idols (PratimA) and in the Tantras it is (primarily) Yantras.

> Yantram mantramayam proktam devatA mantrarupini |
>  Yantre sA pujitA
>   devi sahsaiva prasidAti ||
>
> O Devi, know the Yantra to be Mantra-mayam (mantra-endowed) and the
>   Deity to be of the form of mantra. If worshipped in Yantra, the deity
>   is appeased instantly.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 6.86**

Besides that, Tantras also say that unless worshipped in a Yantra, the deity is not appeased.

Yet another verse, which indicates the inherent identity between a deity and it's Yantra, is as follows:

> Shariramiva jivasya dipasya snehavat priye |
>  SarveshAmapi devAnAm
>   tathA yantram pratishtitha ||
>
> O Beloved, just like the Jivas have the bodies, the lamps the oil and
>   ghee, likewise, for all deities are laid down their respective
>   Yantras.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 6.88**

So, a Yantra is basically a dynamic graph which can be identified as the respective deity's body. Also, as it is Mantra-mayam, it is also endowed with the divine consciousness of the deity.

So, in other words, there is no difference at all between a deity and it's Yantra. Whatever worship that is offered to a Yantra goes to its respective deity.

Now, it should be easy to understand what Goddess Bagalamukhi Yantra represents.

> Who was the first person who used or we can say was originator of this
>   yantra?

It is Lord Shiva of course, because he has created all the Yantras that we have. Including the various Yantras of his consort.

[Brihat TantrasAra](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm) gives the following verse guiding how the Yantra is formed:

> Tryasram sharasram vrittam astadala padmam ||
>
> First draw a triangle pointing up; over it draw a Sharasram - a
>   six-pointed star which is formed by drawing two triangles one pointing
>   up and one pointing down; over it draw a Vritta - a circle and on it
>   draw an eight-petalled lotus. Finally draw the Bhupura (the squarish
>   enclosure) over the configuration.

> Any other interesting facts (worth sharing) associated with this
>   yantra?

The basic purpose of Bagalamukhi worship is to achieve *Stambhana*, one of the Shat Karmas of Tantras, which basically means to completely paralyze a wicked enemy.

From [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19367/4732):

Lord Shiva says the following about the purpose of Goddess Bagalamukhi's mantra and worship:

> BrhmAstram SampravkshyAmi Sadya Pratyayakarakam |
>  SAdhakAnAm
>   HitArthAya **StambhanAya Cha VairinAm** |
>  Yasyah SmaranmAtrena
>   Pavanohapi SthirAyate |
>
> For the benefit of the devotees and for paralyzing the evil groups
>   of enemy (vairi) I am revealing the Bagalamukhi mantra, which is as
>   powerful as the Brahmastra. This mantra can paralyze anyone or
>   anything. Even the movement of air can be stopped by its mere
>   remembrance, what to say of others.

So, the purpose is Stambhanam or completely paralyzing (or subjugating) one's evil enemy.

Comment: BTW Bagalamukhi is a Mahavidya and one can worship Her for salvation also.The Ishtadevi of Mangala-Graha is Bagala and so She is worshipoed to be saved from the evil effects of Mars also.

Comment: And in Bagalamukhi yantra, there is no ashtadala padma:)

Comment: Wow impressive explanation indeed @rickross !

Comment: @Partha  thr is asta dala padma as per tantra sara, they hv also given a pic of the yantra and a 8 petal lotus is thr, moreover brahmi etc 8 shaktis r to b worshipped on the 8 petals

Comment: @Just_Do_It  np bro, but as partha said the goddess is the bestower of the 4 vargas ,moksha included