# Clarification about eligibility to perform Saraswathi kavacha from devi baghavatham

Tags: mantras, goddess, saraswati, devi-bhagavata-purana

Consider the following words from  [Chapter 4 - On the hymn, worship and Kavaca of Sarasvatī Devī](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57317.html) of devi baghavatham regarding Saraswathi kavacha

> One is worship one’s spiritual Teacher (Guru Deva) according to due
>   rites and ceremonies with clothings, ornaments, and sandalpaste and
>   then fall down prostrate to him and then hold this Kavaca.

These lines are not present in my local language translated book.

My doubt is whether these lines are actually present in the original Sanskrit text?

Another doubt is that whether any person is eligible to perform the following Saraswathi kavcha

> Brahmā said :-- “O Child! What you have asked about the Kavaca of
>   Sarasvatī that is sweet to hear, ordained and worshipped by the Vedas,
>   and the giver of all desired fruits, now hear of that. In the very
>   beginning, the all-pervading Śrī Kṛṣṇa, the Lord of the Rāsa circle,
>   mentioned this Kavaca to me in the holy Brindāvana forest in the abode
>   Goloka at the time of Rāsa in Rāsa Mandala. This is very secret; it is
>   full of holy unheard, wonderful Mantras. Reading this Kavaca and
>   holding it (on one’s arm) Brihaspati has become foremost in matters of
>   intelligence; by the force of this Kavaca Śukrācārya has got his
>   ascendancy over the Daityas; the foremost Muni Vālmikī has become
>   eloquent and skilled in language and has become Kavīndra and
>   Svāyambhuva Manu; holding this Kavaca he has become honoured
>   everywhere. Kaṇāda, Gotama, Kaṇva, Paṇini, Śakatāyana, Dakṣa, and
>   Kātyāyana all have become great authors by virtue of this Kavaca;
>   Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana Veda Vyāsa made the classification of the Vedas and
>   composed the eighteen Purāṇas. Śātātapa, Samvarta, Vaśiṣṭha, Parāsara
>   and Yājñavalkya had become authors by holding and reading this
>   Sarasvatī Kavaca. Ṛṣyaśriṅga, Bhāradvāja, Āstika, Devala, Jaigiṣavya,
>   and Yāyāti all were honoured everywhere by virtue of this Kavaca. O
>   Dvija! The Prajāpati Himself is the Ṛṣi of this Kavaca; Brihatī is its
>   Caṇḍa; and Śāradā Ambikā is its presiding Deity. Its application
>   (Viniyoga) is in the acquisition of spiritual knowlege, in the
>   fruition of any desires or necessities, in composing poems or anywhere
>   wheresoever success is required. May Śrīm Hrīm Sarasvatyai Svāhā
>   protect fully my head; Śrīm Vāgdevatāyai Svāhā, my forehead; Om Hrīm
>   Sarasvatyai Svāhā, my ears always; Om Śrīm Hrīm Bhagabatyai
>   Sarasvatyai Svāhā always my eyes; Aim Hrīm Vāgvādinyai Svāhā, always
>   my nose; Om Hrīm Vidyadhiṣṭhātrī Devyai Svāhā, my lips always; Om Śrīm
>   Hrīm Brahmyai Svāhā my rows of teeth; Aim, this single letter protect
>   my neck; Om Śrīm Hrīm my throat; Śrīm, my shoulders, Om Hrīm
>   Vidyādhiṣṭhātrī Devyai Svāhā, always my chest; Om Hrīm
>   Vidyadhisvarūpāyai Svāhā my navel;  Om Hrīm Klīm Vāṇyai Svāhā my
>   hands; Om Svarva vārnatmī Kāyai Svāhā my feet; and let Om
>   Vāgadhisṭhātridevyai Svāhā protect all my body. Let Om
>   Sarvakanṭhavāsinyai Svāhā protect my east; Let Om Svarvajibhāgra
>   vāsinyai Svāhā, the South-east; Om Aim Hrīm Śrīm Klīm Sarasvatyai
>   budhajananyai Svāhā, my South; Aim Hrīm Śrīm, this three lettered
>   Mantra my South-west; Om Aim Jhibhagravāsinyai Svāhā, my West; Om
>   Svarvam bikāyai Svāhā, my North west; Om Aim Śrīm Klīm Gadyavāsinyai
>   Svāhā my North; Aim Sarvaśāstra vasinyai Svāhā, my North-east; Om Hrīm
>   Sarvapujitayai Svāhā, my top; Hrīm Pustakavasinyai Svāhā my below and
>   let Om Grantha vījasvarupāyai Svāhā protect all my sides. O Nārada!
>   This Viśvajaya Kavaca of the nature of Brahmā and its embodied Mantra
>   I have now spoken to you. I heard this before from the mouth of Dharma
>   Deva in the Gaṇdhāmādana mountain. Now I speak this to you out of my
>   great affection for you. But never divulge this to anybody. **One is
>   worship one’s spiritual Teacher (Guru Deva) according to due rites and
>   ceremonies with clothings, ornaments, and sandalpaste and then fall
>   down prostrate to him and then hold this Kavaca.** Repeating this five
>   lakhs of times, one gets success and becomes a Siddha. The holder of
>   this Kavaca becomes intelligent like Brihaspati, eloquent, Kavīndras,
>   and the conqueror of the three worlds, no sooner one becomes a Siddlha
>   in this. In fact, he can conquer everything by virtue of this Kavaca.
>   O Muni! Thus I have described to you this Kavaca according to Kāṇva
>   Śākhā. Now I am speaking about the method of worship, Dhyāna and the
>   praise of this Kavaca. Hear.
>
> [[62-91, Chapter 4 - On the hymn, worship and Kavaca of Sarasvatī Devī,Book 9, Devi baghavatham]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57317.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the lines you quoted in your question are actually present in original Devi Bhagavata Purana. The passage is a translation of  Shloka no. 88 -Chapter4 - Book 9. Below is the [**original Sanskrit shloka**](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%AF/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%AA).

> गुरुमभ्यर्च्य विधिवद्वस्त्रालङ्‌कारचन्दनैः ।
>  प्रणम्य दण्डवद्‍भूमौ
>   कवचं धारयेत्सुधीः ॥ 88 ॥
>
> One is worship one’s spiritual Teacher (Guru Deva) according to due
>   rites and ceremonies with clothing, ornaments, and sandal paste and
>   then fall down prostrate to him and then hold this Kavaca.

---

## Whether any person is eligible to perform the following Saraswathi kavcha?

There are several posts present here on Hinduism SE about your doubt of eligibility of  Upasana , chanting of mantras, the practice of Tantra etc. 
Here in the passage you quoted is related to Tantric as well as Vedic Upasana of Goddess Saraswati. This kavacha contains many tantric mantras like

**`Om Śrīm Hrīm Bhagabatyai Sarasvatyai Svāhā`**

Now let's see some of the answers from here.

In the below [**answer**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34282/can-yantra-and-mantra-work-without-diksha-from-guru/34285#34285) we can clearly see that  twice-born persons who are not initiated by Guru are not entitled to practice mantra, tantra and worship of the deities. As mentioned in Gautamiya -Tantra.

> dvijAtinAm anupanitAm svakarma-adhyanAdishu/yathA adhikaram nasti iha
>   sandhyA-upAsanA-karmasu/tathA hi adikshitAnAm tu
>   mantra-tantra-archanAdishu/na adhikaro'sti atah kuryAd AtmAnam
>   shiva-sanskritam// (chapter 5).
>
> Meaning: Just like twice-borns are not entitled to do sandhyavandana
>   (with Gayatri mantra japa) and study of the scriptures, the people
>   without diksha from Guru are not entitled to practice mantra, tantra
>   and worship of the deities. Therefore one should get initiated.

---

Here is another [**answer**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31559/what-is-initiation-of-mantra/31580#31580) from @Rickross mentioning the importance of initiation of mantra or mantra Diksha from guru

> PAramparyAgamAmnAyam mantra AchArAdikam priye | Sarvam
>   gurumukhAllabdham saphalam syAnna chAnyathA ||
>
> Traditions, Agama, Amnaya, Mantras, conducts and other similar things,
>   O Beloved one, are fruitful only if obtained from Guru's mouth and not
>   otherwise.- KulArnava Tantram 11.46

---

Answer - So looking from above two examples, we can say that it is most advisable to get initiation of the tantric mantras mentioned in the passage of Devi Bhagavata Purana from a teacher before chanting them and to seek proper guidance from guru in practising them in order to make them fruitful. However, one can perform general puja of a deity as mentioned in the chapter with 16 upacharas and with devotional songs , arati etc. without chanting of mantras.

Comment: We are living in Kali yuga, Finding a true guru is difficult, who knows it may consume half of the person's life line in finding a guru. But the count to true guru is dangerously less to the population. 

By your answer are you concluding that,

"not entitled to practice mantra, tantra and worship of the deities"

If yes I am quiet sure that more that half of this world's population is in-eligible to chant mantras, worship a deity.

In Kali yuga to my knowledge what God says is "Do whatever you want with love and I'll take you back home"

Comment: I request you to provide a logical explanation which matches to Kali Yuga. You just cannot tell he or she is ineligible to worship a diety just because he/she cannot find a Guru.

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM: Naama Japa is different from mantra Japa. Naama japa involves recitation of name of a deity, say **rAma**, fir certain number of times.  It is like calling your parents .   Even if you spell it wrongly,  or forget to do for some days, etc,  no harm will come to you .  No initiation by a guru  is required here.

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM: in mantra japa,  you will be reciting bIjAksharas like **hrIm**.  Here you require guidance.    Basically recitation of bIjAksharas will activate certain nerve centres resulting in release of energy.   If not properly done,  the release of energy may not occur causing frustration in the reciter or may cause harm also, which is also not good.   As energy from lower levels start climbing up,  one tend become arrogant with power which is again harmful.   So guidance of an accomplished Guru,  will check this.

Comment: With appricieating your concern. My answer deals with the specific query of OP regarding Devi kavacha. It's not about general deity worship but regarding chanting of Tantic mantras present  in that kavacha , chanting of which requires initiation. Besides I have already explained that those who are not initiated can still perform the general puja/Upasana vidhi without chanting of Tantric/Vedic mantras. This does not mean that one can not carry out Upasana or worship of a deity outrightly.

Comment: But should refrain from practising the procedure of worship, chanting of vedic /Tantric mantras unless initiated. And this is quite clearly and repeatedly mentioned throughout Hinduism scriptures as well.Yes, it is quite difficult to find a Guru in this age as said by you. But still all is not lost , there are lot's of peethas in India where we can find knowledgeable persons who can guide us about the deity worship and can give us an initiation. e.g. Shakti peethas. Here is the wiki link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakti_Peetha#The_List_of_Shakti_Peethas

Comment: @srimannarayanakv - Thanks for the explanation.:- )