# Who is NityA Devi Goddess

Tags: goddess, devi, shaktism

Would like to know more about NityA Devi Goddess.
Does this Goddess belongs to DasaMahavidyas? if not, any relation with Goddessess in SriVidya Krama.

Is the below , Her dhyana ?

> ArdgendumaulimarunAmamarAbhivandyAmambhojapAsha srini purnakapAla hastAm ||

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, NityA Devi, whose half-dhyanam you have quoted, is not part of the Dasha Mahavidyas. She is worshipped independently. Outside of Sri Vidya or Maha Vidya worship.

[Brihat Tantra SArah](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm) gives her puja prayog and mantra as follows:

> Atha nityAmantrah:
>
> vAgbhvam kAmabijancha nityAklinnemadau punah |
>   dravei vahni badhur mantro dvAdashArnoyamiritah ||

Decoded, the mantra is:

> Aim klim nityAklinne mada drave swAhA

The Rishi-Chandah-DevatA are Sammohana Rishi-Nivrit-NityA.

> is the below , HER dhyana ?

That is only part of the whole DhyAnam. I quoted only that much in the other answer because there I had only to prove that she holds a skull-cup.

Her full DhyAnam is as given below:

> ArdhendumaulimarunAmamarAbhivandyAmbhoja pAsha shrini purna
>   kapAla-hastAm |
>  RaktAnga rAga vasanAbharanAm trinetrAm
>   dhyAyechivasya vanitAm mada vihvalAngim ||
>
> The deity has crescent moon on her forehead, has three eyes, she is of reddish
>   complexion and is worshipped by the gods. She has four arms and in the
>   hands she holds - a lotus, pAsha (noose), Vajra and a human skull. She is
>   wearing red color clothes and is decked with ornaments ..

This form of the Goddess is not worshipped within Sri VidyA.

The following is a picture of her Yantra (a Yantra always helps identifying the deity better):

[image]

Comment: yes, thats what i mentioned.i forgot the source.thanks:)

Comment: Oh of this form of Devi? @Partha

Comment: @Rickross Swamin, if you have a pic of this Devi, can you please share the link/soure ...  So, Nitya Devi is altogether having a different form.!! okay!! Dhanyosmi...

Comment: Don't call me Swamin, coz that will be an insult to each Swamis that exist :P  im just a disciple .. Btw I don't hv a pic right now, will keep your request in mind @SaMolPP

Comment: @SaMolPP Nitya Devi is a Kali Kula deity and not a Sri Kula deity.. See my [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20173/4732) .. In Tantrasara, Nitya Devi's worship is given after giving those of Annapurna, Tvarita, Triputa etc who are all from Kali Kula

Answer (score 2):

Nityaa is a feminine form of Nitya (Eternal).Devi Adya-Shakti is eternal.

The mantra 64 of Chapter 1 of Sri Sri Chandi reads

> **Nityaa** eva saa jagan-murtis tayaa sarvam idam tatam, meaning Goddess is Nityaa, the entire world is Her body and She is All-pervading.

**This is the most beautiful depiction of Nityaa.**

So ALL the forms of Mother Goddess that we worship are Nitya.

Yes, Dasa-Mahavidyaas are also Nityaa-s.

In specific purana, some particular form of Devi has been also named as Nityaa along with Vajra-prastarini.I do not have the reference with me at this moment.Hope someone wil be providing the details of that form.

But I repeat, All forms are Nityaa and Sri Sri Chandi is the most respected scripture among all the scriptures depicting the Mother Goddess.

**Update**

Nityaa alongwith Lalita and Vajra-prastarini, Annapurna etc are the devies of the Purva-Aamnaaya, according to Devyaagama-vachana in Tantra-Rahasya. Lalita is one name of Srividya. So according to this scripture, these two are related. (Reference: Sastramulak Bharatiya Saktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das,RMIC, vol 2, page 1049).But Sri Vidya explicitly is treated in the Samayachaara-Tantra as belonging to Purva-Aamnaya, and there Nitya is not mentioned.

Comment: i have edited my question. so,I hope, this is not NityaClinna Devi. i observed, the Dhyana of NityaClinna Devi and another Goddess remains same. But the moolamantra differs!! Can this happen?

Comment: @SaMolPP I have never seen same dhyana with different moolamantra, But if it is there in any scripture, that has to be accepted.Nothing is impossible for the ONE Who has infinite forms and mantras.

Comment: Annapurna, Triputa, Tvarita, Nitya etc are Kali Kula deities (Tantrasara also gives Nitya puja after Annapurna, Triputa and Tvarita's worship) .. see this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20173  I hv also read the amnaya bhedas in one book .. will chk that if an update in my answer is required @Partha

Comment: @Partha, Swamin,  "I have never seen same dhyana with different moolamantra," ---> I have seen this in a PoojaGrantha. This Nitya Devi and NityClinna having the same dhyana but with different Moolamantra ! but, am not sure whether this wrong or not!  or is it a mistake from the author!  Anyway , thanks for your details.