# Who is Goddess Tvarita?

Tags: mantras, worship, goddess, devi

Recently I have heard about goddess named **"Tvarita"** and I want to know this form of goddess. So my questions are:

- Who is goddess Tvarita and why she is called so?
- How she is depicted in the scriptures?
- What is the mode of her worship?
- What are her basic Mantras?

I am expecting brief answers with reference from the Puranas or Tantras.

Comment: She is one of the protector goddesses of the Sri Chakra. One among the fifteen Nityas... I think @Rickross can help you with this question. He is very very knowledgable about Tantra, and can give you a clear answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can give a partial answer here.

TvaritA is so called because she gives results quickly (from the word *tvarita* meaning *quick*).

I know her mode of worship which is Tantric in nature and the relevant verses are quoted in the [Brihat TantrasArah](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm). The text however does not specify which of the Tantras it is quoting from.

> Atha tvaritA mantrah ||
>
> athAbhidhAsye tvaritAm tvaritam phaladAyinim |
>  TAromAyA
>   varma-bijam riddhi-rishasvarAsvitA ||
>  Kurmastadanto bhagavAn
>   kshatri-dirgha-tanucchadam |
>  Samvarto bhagavAn maya-phatanto
>   dvAdashAksharah |
>  MAyA bhuvanshi varma hum riddhi kha-karah
>   ishwarah e-kArah kurmashcha-kArah tadantash-chakArah bhaga
>   ekarastada-yuktah kshah stri swarupam dirgha-tanucchadam hum
>   samvartakah ksha-kArah bhaga e-kArastada-yuktah punarbhuvaneswari phat
>   ||

These verses at the start is saying that quick results follow if one chants the TvaritA mantra. And then the verses are giving the mantra in a coded form.

tvaritAm tvaritam phaladAyinim -- Goddess TvaritA gives quick results. So, this gives you an idea why she is so called.

The decoded mantra is -- Om hrim hum khechache kshastri hum kshe hrim phat

It's a 12-letter mantra whose Rishi (seer) is stated to be Arjuna (from MahAbhArata).

> AsyArjunarishi-virAta chandah tvaritadevatA purushArtha-chatushtaya
>   siddhyarthe viniyogah |
>
> For the mantra, Arjuna is the Rishi, VirAt is the Chandah and TvaritA
>   is the DevatA. For accomplishing the four goals of life, the chanting
>   is being done.

Then the method her worship is given. DhyAna sloka, NyAsa mantras etc are given in the text. The Purascharana of the mantra is accomplished by one lakh chants.

The Puja is to be done using the deity's Yantra which looks like:

[image]

In the Yantra, inside all the petals the Bija Hum is to be inscribed whereas in the circle the Bija Hrim. And, inside the circle, clockwise, all the 50 letters of Sanskrit are also to be inscribed.

The Devi's description is detailed in her DhyAna sloka and which is as follows:

> ShyAmAm vahir-kalApa-shekhara-yutAmA-vaddha-parnAmshukAm |
>   Gunja-hAralasat-payodharanatAmashtAhipAn vibhratim ||
>   TArankAngad-mekhalA-guna-ranan-manjiratAm prApitAn |
>  KairAtim
>   varadAbhayodyatakarAm devim trinetrAm bhaje ||
>  Evam dhyAtvA
>   mAnaseyih sampujya shankha-sthApanam kuryAt ....
>
> The Devi is having dark complexion. She has a crown in the head which
>   is having peacock's tail. Her garments are made of leaves. She is
>   wearing necklace that is made of Gunja flowers (rosary pea). The hem
>   of the cloth which is made of eight snakes is hanging down to the
>   weight of her breasts. She is decked with armlets, waist-chain and
>   anklets. She is having three eyes and has the appearance of a KirAta. On
>   one hand she shows the boon-giving gesture and on the other the
>   fear-dispelling one.
>
> Upon meditating thus one has to do the mental worship and thereafter
>   establish the conch etc ...

And, as shown in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20173), Devi TvaritA belongs to the KAli Kula and not to the Sri Kula.

Comment: Who will give me the upadesha of this mantra? 

Comment: I mean,  initiation***,

Comment: I don't know that :) @SaMolPP

Comment: i think, this is not a swatwik murthy, its purely thamasik! may be , need to perform the upasana in the night? there is a beeja mantra "khe kshe" !! never heard abt this!!

Comment: Tamas and Sattva lie in our minds and nowhere else .. You have heard all Beejas? and those which you have not heard about will be tamsik? @SaMolPP

Comment: _/\_ am sorry, am a nobody to counter-point you here...

Comment: No problem its ok bro :) @SaMolPP

Answer (score 3):

Similarly Just like the Tantric scriptures  the goddess "Tvarita" is also discussed in puranas ,  we find  very detailed description of her in Agni Purana. Below  are the chapter names from Agni Purana.

1) Agni Purana - Part 2 - Chapter 147 - Mode of worshiping goddess Tvarita and others.

2)  Agni Purana - Part  3 - Chapter 309 - Mode of worshiping goddess Tvarita.

3 )  Agni Purana - Part 3  - Chapter 310 - Narration of the spell relating to Tvarita.

4 ) 1) Agni Purana - Part 3 - Chapter 311  - Location of the basic mantras of  Tvarita and her worship.

---

According to Agni purana the name Tvarita means the goddess conferring benefits quickly also by worshiping her one gets enjoyment and emancipation . Ancient times lord took form of hunter the goddess Gauri also took similar  form ,which is known as  "Tvarita"  We find her description in the same.

## Description

> मयूरबलया पिच्छमौलिः किसलयांशुका । 
>  सिंहासनस्था
>   मायूरवर्हच्छत्रसमन्विता ।। 309.4 ।।
>  त्रिनेत्रा श्यामला देवी
>   वनमालाविभूषणा ।
>  विप्राहिकर्णाभरणा क्षत्रकेयूरभूषणा ।। 309.5 ।।
>
> [**3b-6**](https://archive.org/details/AgniPuranaUnabridgedEnglishMotilal/page/n865)  The goddess has to be contemplated as having form of
>   daughter of the mountain , huntress , supreme , conferring boons  and
>   protection , having peacock feathers on the head , having the tender
>   sprout as the upper garment. Seated on lion throne  together with
>   umbrella of peacock plumes , the dark complexioned goddess wearing the
>   garland of wild flowers.

---

## Worship

> Fire-God said -: 
>  अग्निरुवाच
>  त्वरिताङ्गान्समाख्यास्ये
>   भुक्तिमुक्तिप्रदायकान् ।
>  ओं आधारशक्त्यै नमः । ओं ह्रीँ पुरु
>   महासिंहाय नमः ।
>  ओं पद्माय नमः । ओं ह्रीँ ह्रूँ खेचछेक्षः । स्त्रीँ
>   ओं ह्रूँ क्षैँ ह्रूँ फट्
>  त्वरितायै नमः । खे च हृदयाय नमः । चछे
>   शिरसे नमः ।
>  छेक्षः शिखायै नमः । क्षस्त्री कवचाय नमः । स्त्रीँ
>   ह्रूँ नेत्राय नमः ।
>  ह्रूँ खे अस्त्राय फट् नमः ।। [**309.1**](https://archive.org/details/AgniPuranaUnabridgedEnglishMotilal/page/n865) ।।
>
> 1 I shall describe (to you) the constituent (mantras) (relating to the
>   worship ) of Tvarita that is capable of conferring enjoyment and
>   emancipation . "Om obeisance to the supportive energy ! Om hrim puru
>   (2) obeisance  to great lion ! Om obeisance to the lotus ! Om hrim
>   hrum khecacheksah ! Shrim om hrum ksaim hrim phat ! obeisance to
>   goddes Tvarita ! ka ca  obeisance to heart ! Cache obeisance  to head
>   ! Cheksah obeisance to the tuft !  Ksastri obeisance  to the armor !
>   Shrim hrum  obeisance to the eye ! hrum khe obeisance to the weapon 
>   phat.
>
> ---
>
> 8-10  अष्टसिंहासने पूज्या दले पूर्वादिके क्रमात् । 
>  अङ्गणायत्री
>   प्रणीता हूङ्काराद्या दलग्रके ।। 309.8 ।। 
>  Goddess tvarita has to
>   be worshipped in a lion seat (having) eight peatals . Gayatri ,Pranita
>   ,humkara etc. and phatkari are located in the peatals in the east etc.

---

[**Agni Purana Chapter 310**](https://archive.org/details/AgniPuranaUnabridgedEnglishMotilal/page/n867) is also describing the worship of goddess Tvarita with Yantra.

> Fire god said - :
>
> I shall describe (to you) the worship of Tvaraita by another method
>   that would yield enjoyment and emancipation.One has to worship the
>   Goddess in a diagram of the shape of a thunderbolt drawn with dust.
>   One has to draw a lotus inside it .One has to contemplate the goddess
>   and draw quickly eight thunderbolts in the main direction and the
>   intermediate directions and also draw pathway , entrance ,ornamental 
>   arch and secondary decoration . (One has to worship goddess ) as
>   having eighteen hands and her left shank placed on the lion . Two fold
>   fee should be offered at her pedestal (She should be worshiped ) in
>   the sacrificial pit in the form of thunder bolt as been adorned by
>   serpents and as holding the sword , disc ,mace ,spike , arrow in the
>   right hands and as confirming boons and as holding the bow ,noose ,
>   arrow , bell , threatening posture of the first finger , conch , goad
>   and thunderbolt in the left hands and offering protection .