# Who is Adi Parashakthi? Is this the creator of the Trimurtis?

Tags: devi, goddess, shakti, shaktism

- **Paramatma** is said to be one is Eternal,Formless and etc,... **Source of Creation**.
- We also know Adi Parashakthi and is said to be the **Divine Mother** and source of Energy.
- Also said to be **Creator of Trimurthi's**.

**MY QUESTION :**

- Who is **Adi Parashakthi**? Is this the creator of the Trimurtis?

Comment: From Shakta perspective, She is creator of trimurthis.

Comment: @TheDestroyer friend thanks My doubt is does some other puranas says about it and why she is called Adi Parashakthi

Comment: Actually, we're using 'she' just to denote 'this' aspect of ultimate reality. Adi Parāshakti is genderless actually. Adi Shakti is power of creation or It is creation itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are many references in Puranas and agamas (shaiva and shakta) about the actual origin of the creation. Without her creative force nothing else is possible. All the living and non living objects are due to her creative energy.

**Regarding Adi parA shakti:**

> 1-50. The Devî said :-- "Hear, Ye Immortals! My words with attention,
>   that I am now going to speak to you, hearing which will enable the
>   Jîvas to realise My Essence. Before the creation, I, only I, existed;
>   nothing else was existent then. My Real Self is known by the names
>   Chit, Sambit (Intelligence), Para Brahma and others. My Âtman is
>   beyond mind, beyond thought, beyond any name or mark, without any
>   parallel, and beyond birth, death or any other change or
>   transformation. My Self has one inherent power called Mâyâ. This Mâyâ
>   is not existent, nor non-existent, nor can it be called both. This
>   unspeakable substance Mâyâ always exists (till the final emancipation
>   or Moksa).
>
> I am Nirguna. And when I am united with my S'aktî, Mâyâ, 1 become
>   Saguna, the Great Cause of this world. This Mâyâ is divided into two,
>   Vidyâ and Avidyâ. Avidyâ Mâyâ hides Me; whereas Vidyâ Mâyâ does not.
>   Avidyâ creates whereas Vidyâ Mâyâ liberates. (Devi Bhagvatam)
>
> In Hinduism, Shakti (Devanagari: शक्ति; from Sanskrit shak, "to be
>   able"), also spelled as Sakthi, meaning "power" or "empowerment" is
>   the primordial cosmic energy and represents the dynamic forces that
>   are thought to move through the entire universe. Shakti is the
>   concept or personification of divine feminine creative power,
>   sometimes referred to as 'The Great Divine Mother' in Hinduism. As the
>   mother she is known as Adi Parashakti or Adishakti. On the earthly
>   plane, Shakti most actively manifests through female embodiment and
>   creativity/fertility, though it is also present in males in its
>   potential, unmanifest form. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakti))
>
> According to Shaktism and Hindu mythology, Adi Para Shakti—the
>   Goddess, Devi—is the Supreme Being. She is also popularly referred to
>   as "Adi Shakti", "Parama Shakti", "Maha Shakti", "Mahadevi", or even
>   simply as "Shakti". "Parama" means absolute, "Satya" means the Truth
>   as per many Shakta texts.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakti) The Devi Bhagawata Mahapurana states that
>   Adi Parashakti is the original creator, observer and destroyer of the
>   whole universe. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Parashakti))
>
> **Regarding Tri-murtis:**
>
> > 38-43. O Lord of Rama! I am sprung from the lotus from thy navel and
> >     have become the Lord of this whole universe; **who is there in this
> >     universe that is superior to Thee; kindly say this to me.** O Lord of
> >     the world? Thou art the Origin of all, the Cause of all causes, the
> >     Creator, Preserver and Destroyer and the capable Doer of all actions.
> >     O Maharaja! at Thy will, I create this whole universe and Rudra
> >     destroys iu due time this world. He is always under Thy command. O
> >     Lord! By Thy command the Sun roams in the sky; the wind blows in
> >     various auspicious or inauspicious ways and the fire is giving heat
> >     and the cloud showers rain. I don’t see in the three Lokas any one
> >     superior to Thee. Then whom art Thou meditating while being questioned
> >     by his very intelligent son S’uka Deva! not born in the usual way from
> >     womb, Dvaipâyana expounded all the secret excellent meanings of the
> >     Purâna and thereby I also came to know them also. O saintly persons!
> >     Thus S’uka Deva, sincerely earnest to cross this endless bottomless
> >     ocean of S’amsara, tasted of the wonderful traits of the Veda, the
> >     Kalpa tree, this S’rimad Bhâgavata with its numerous stories and
> >     anecdotes with great eagerness and intense pleasure.
>
> 44-50. Thus hearing Brahmâ's words, Bhagavan Nârâyana spoke :-- “O
>   Brahmân! I now speak out my mind to you; listen carefully. Though the
>   Devas, Dânavas and men and all the Lokas know that You are the
>   Creator, I am the Preserver and Rudra is the Destroyer, **yet it is to
>   be known that the saints, versed in the Vedas, have come to this
>   conclusion by inference from the Vedas that the creation,
>   preservation, and destruction are performed by the creative force,**
>   preservative force and destructive force. The Rajasik creative force
>   residing in you, the  Sattvik preservative force residing in me, and
>   the Tamasik destructive force residing in Rudra are the all-in-all.
>   **When these Saktis become absent, you become inert and incapable to
>   create, I to preserve and Rudra to destroy.**
>
> O intelligent Suvrata! **We all are always under that Force directly or
>   indirectly; hear instances that you can see and infer.** At the time of
>   Pralaya, I lie down on the bed of Ananta, subservient to that Force;
>   again I wake up in the time of creation duly under the influence of
>   Time.
>
> 51-54. **I am always subservient to that Maha S’akti; (under Her
>   command) I am engaged in Tapasyâ for a long time;** (By Her command)
>   some time I enjoy with Lakshmî; some time I fight battles, terrible to
>   all the Lokas, with the Dânavas, involving great bodily troubles. O
>   Know of Dharma! It was before Your presence that I fought hand to hand
>   fight for five thousand  years before
>
> 55-61. O highly fortunate one! **you realised then the great S’akti,
>   higher than the highest and the cause of all causes**; then why are you
>   asking again and again that question. By the will of that S’akti, I
>   have got this idea of man and roam on the great ocean; **in yuga after
>   yuga, I assume by Her will, the Tortoise, Boar, Man-Lion, and Dwarf
>   incarnations. No one likes to take birth in the womb of inferior
>   animals (especially birds). Do you think that I willingly take
>   unpleasant births as in the womb of boars, tortoise, i.e., certainly
>   not.** What independent man is there who abandons the pleasurable
>   enjoyment with Laksmi and takes birth in inferior animals as fish,
>   etc. or leaves his seat on the seat of Gaduda and becomes engaged in
>   great war-conflicts. O Svayambhu! In ancient days you saw before your
>   eyes that my head was cut off when the bowstring suddenly gave way;
>   and then you, brought a horse's head and by that help, the divine
>   artist Visvakarma, stuck that on to my headless body. O Brahmâ! Since
>   then I am known amongst men by the name of  “Hayagrîva”. This is
>   well-known to you. Now say, were I independent, would such an ignominy
>   have happened to me? Never. **Therefore I am not independent; I am in
>   every way under that S’akti. O Lotus-born! I always meditate on that
>   S’akti; and I do not know any other than this S’akti**”.

[Devi Bhagvat Purana 4.1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk01ch04.htm)

Comment: friend your answer gives that this is the creator of Trimurthi but what is Adi Parashakthi You didn't answer

Comment: It has the answer also read carefully. if still not find sufficient then i will edit further.

Comment: i readed and even used find in page your answer does not have  one  word of adi parashakthi IT HAS ONLY SAKTHI OR SAKTI

Comment: friend i think Shakti and Adi Parasakthi have different meanings and Not Interchangable ones

Comment: friend can you tell  what is the problem ?