# What are the 10 Vishnu incarnations of Devi Lalitha?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, devi

I heard that from the finger nails of devi, 10 incarnations of Vishnu originated. Is it true? If yes, what are the 10 incarnations and from which finger nail which incarnations have come?

Comment: I hv answered here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32637/4732 But im not sure if this is truly a duplicate or not

Comment: If ur Q does not turn out to be a duplicate thn I will delete my answer there and post it here .. The answer is more suitable here