# Who was Kohlaasura? How did Mother Lakshmi kill him?

Tags: scripture, lakshmi, asuras, devi

What is story behind him?  Is the story written in some Scriptures? How did Mother kill him?

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/kolasura-bhayam-kari-lakshmi-ashtakam

Comment: @SwiftPushkar this post I had already read. Ko kasur story is not found in any scriptures. I read a translation where kolasur was translated to be Shani Deva- http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/mahaalakshmyashhTakaM.html?lang=sa   . And the website is a reputed one, so it might not have just written as such.

Comment: @Narasimham I had deliberately written in question- "How did 'killed' ", to see if anyone would even notice. And you did. ;)

Comment: But yes the other mistakes I myself took no note of.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Who was Kolhaasura?

- He was demon of the form of a boar. He was frightening the tri-lokas.

#### 2. Is the story written in some Scriptures?

- Yes, it is briefly rederenced to in the
  Skandamahāpurāṇam 4.1.5.78.

#### 3. How did Mother kill him?

- The Skanda Purāṇa doesn't explicitly specify that, how did she kill him. But we may assume, considering she's a great goddess, it won't take much effort on her part to kill a demon.

#### Scriptural References?

Skanda Purāṇa Verse 4.1.5.(73 to 78).

> [Chapter 5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423742.html), Pūrvārdha, Kāśī-khaṇḍa
>
> तत्रागस्त्यो महालक्ष्मीं ददृशे सुचिरं स्थिताम् ॥ ७५ ॥
>
> > 75. **Rishi Agastya, the mass of merit, the storehouse of penance, saw in
> >     front of him Goddess Mahālakṣmī (of Kolhapur) like a lucky man, the
> >     best of glory.**
>
> ......
>
> त्रैलोक्यं कोलरूपेण त्रासयंतं महासुरम् । 
> विनिहत्य स्थितां तत्र
> रम्ये कोलापुरे पुरे ॥ ७८ ॥
>
> > 78. **A great Asura was frightening the three worlds in the form of a boar.
> >     The goddess killed that demon and stayed in the beautiful city of
> >     Kolhapur ever since.**
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare

Comment: the references are already in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/who-spoke-the-lakshmi-ashtakam-did-lakshmi-really-kill-kolhasura  the main question (how did mother Lakshmi kill him) is not answered.

Comment: It's already specified under the heading 3, that the Skanda Purāṇa doesn't mention how did she kill him. She just did. We cannot know. And in the main question, the references **are not** there. The questionet quotes a stotra which is attributed to Padma Purāṇa, but isn't even found in the Padma Purana. @SK. The Main question has three parts, not just one.